# UIScrollView with over 100 images

Tags: iphone, image, uiscrollview, paging

I have implemented a UIScrollView on the iPhone that contains 100 image slots which I fill only the currently visible page, the one before it, and the one after it as the user scrolls.

Everything works fine until we get up to image 97 or 98, the entire view disappears! The only thing I can do at that point is navigate back to the previous view.

Nothing works as far as the scroll view after this. I am not receiving any memory warnings an the rest of the app functions fine. Any ideas? Has anyone created a UIScrollView in paging mode with over 100 pages?

Rick

Answer (score 1):

you might want to look into using the Three20 library.

http://three20.info/ (open source and commercial friendly license)

It has an 'image container', might save you some time on re-inventing the wheel.